# how to call SOAP web service in pycharm?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, pycharm

I want to call **soap web service** by python in pycharm IDE where all inputs must sign by private key by SHA1 algorithm. Please suggest a library or methods.

sample c# code:

```cs
    public string GetDepositBalance(string username, string depositNumber)
    {
        UserServices service = new UserServices();
        string request = string.Format("{{\"Username\":\"{0}\",\"Timestamp\":\"{1}\",\”DepositNumber\”:\”{2}\”}}",
        username, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), depositNumber);
        return service.GetDepositBalance(request, GetSignature(request));
    }
    private static string GetSignature(string data)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        csp.FromXmlString(privateKey);
        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        byte[] signatureBytes = csp.SignData(inputBytes, "SHA1");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
    }
```

I want to implement this script in **python**. 
Tanks.